# MATLAB: computations involving large numbers

Tags: matlab, stack-overflow

How can one perform computations in MATLAB that involve large numbers. As a simple example, an arbitrary precision calculator would show that ((1/120)^132)*(370!)/(260!) is approximately 1.56, but MATLAB is not able to perform such a computation (`power(120,-132)*factorial(370)/factorial(260)` = `NaN`).

I have also tried the following, which does not work:

```
syms a b c d;
a=120; b=-132; c=370; d=260;
f=sym('power(a,b)*gamma(c+1)/gamma(d+1)')
double(f); % produces error that instructs use of `vpa`
vpa(f) % produces (gamma(c + 1.0)*power(a, b))/gamma(d + 1.0)
```

Comment: Even reaching the recursion limit of 500 would probably be an indication of bad program/algorithm design. Why does your code require such a deep recursion in the first place?

Comment: I am trying to compute quantities involving very large factorials and powers, and do not have access to the symbolic math toolkit. The quantity turns out to be within a couple orders of magnitude of unity, but the terms entering the expression are rather much larger. I am therefore using recursion to evaluate the factorials and powers in smaller step sizes (I suppose I could increase the number of steps per recursion level and thereby commensurately reduce the recursion depth required). I could also evaluate the quantities using loops, but I find recursion to be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Factorials and powers can be easily computed without recursion. If you are computing large factorials, beware that double valued Matlab variables won't be precise enough to store them anyway.

Comment: Values larger than 170! equate to infinity (`Inf`) in MATLAB. I need to compute terms that involve N! where N can be thousands or millions. How can such a value be computed without symbolic math?

Comment: Perhaps you should post your code so far and the expressions that you are trying to evaluate.

Comment: If you are trying to avoid a stack overflow, why are you here? :)

Comment: I don't think this is the answer you want, but I have had a much more enjoyable experience using Mathematica rather than Matlab for large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to calculate the factorial of some large numbers, you can use the Java arbitrary precision tools, like so:

```
result = java.math.BigDecimal(1);
for ix = 1:300
    result = result.multiply(java.math.BigDecimal(ix));
end
disp(result)
306057512216440636035370461297268629388588804173576999416776741259476533176716867465515291422477573349939147888701726368864263907759003154226842927906974559841225476930271954604008012215776252176854255965356903506788725264321896264299365204576448830388909753943489625436053225980776521270822437639449120128678675368305712293681943649956460498166450227716500185176546469340112226034729724066333258583506870150169794168850353752137554910289126407157154830282284937952636580145235233156936482233436799254594095276820608062232812387383880817049600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The value `result` in this case is a java object.  You can see the available methods here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

I'm still not sure that I would trust this method for `(1e6)!` though.  You'll have to experiment and see.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you're trying to do, then you may be able to evaluate the expression you're interested in in log-space:

```
log_factorial = sum(log(1:300));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to approximate large factorials and simplify your expression before computing it numerically.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:
`vpa('120^-132*370!/260!')`

and the result is 
`1.5625098001612564605522837520443`