# Large numbers multiplication in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a question out of sheer curiosity. How is multiplication of large numbers implemented in MATLAB ? Is it Karatsuba,Toom-3, Fürer or something entirely different ?

Comment: There's an [interesting thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/164051) that I've found in MATLAB Central that may be related to your problem...

Comment: Thanks ! that certainly is interesing. Now I know I can use symbolic toolbox to make this kind of operation. Unfortunately it doesn't say anything about how exactly it is implemented or what algorithm is used. Anyway, thanks for comment !

Comment: If you do not *aim for accuracy, but for speed*, then what are your large numbers? Can they be 'approximately' represented by doubles? like 1e254? What is big? Do you need arbitrary precision arithmetic? You say you want large number multiplication, but then you say you do not care about accuracy. What does that mean?

Comment: [There was a thread about large numbers in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337342/matlab-computations-involving-large-numbers). How is that different from what you need?

Comment: Let's say I am only interested in algorithm, which is used when I try to compute something like this: 139676498390139139676498390676498390*8745566554641239676498390676498390

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in the algorithm for computing for example `139676498390139139676498390676498390*8745566554641239676498390676498390`, then this is what happens:

- both numbers are converted to `double` in [IEEE® Standard 754](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html)
- as such, the representation is not accurate, because `doubles` can only accurately represent integers of up to [`2^53-1` (check documentation of `bitmax` function)](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bitmax.html) (~`10^15`, while your numbers are on the order of `10^35`).
- multiplication is performed using double precision floating point numbers, and is thus also approximate

Have a look at this example code:

```
>> a=139676498390139139676498390676498390;
>> num2str(a)

ans =

139676498390139141600015724509659136
```

which is clearly not exactly the value you assigned to `a` - only the first 16 digits match.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in `BigInteger` class, if that is what you mean. You can either use the fixed point toolbox, or import relevant java/.NET classes.

By default, numbers are represented in IEEE double precision floating point format.

Comment: What about the symbolic toolkit?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer, if you need more digits of accuracy, you can try to use this [fex file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36534-hpf-a-big-decimal-class)

Comment: I do not aim for accuracy, but for speed of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are only big, but you don't require a large number of significant digits. You can multiple a small number with each multiplication, such as $10^-1$. Keep track of the number of multiplications $N$ and obtain a value in terms of $10^{-N}$. This can be a temporary work around.